# Set hidden values for popup lov

Tags: popup, oracle-apex, lov

I am trying to use a oracle apex popup lov. Everything works fine. My PLSQL query returns a list of values and it's getting displayed correctly. The question now is if there is a way to store hidden values to theses query results?

For example: The query gets me a list of usernames and their id's. Now i only want to show the username and get the id with plsql later from the popup lov item.

I noticed there is always a HIDDENVALUE item comming with a popup lov. Is this relevant? How to use it?

Thanks in advance,
Filip.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get additional attributes for all the values that can possibly be selected by in the popup lov ? Or just for the selected value ?

Comment: @Koen Lostrie I need only additional attributes for the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "additional outputs" attributes of the popup lov. It allows to set another page item to one of the column values of the query when a value is selected.

In my example I have defined a 3rd column in my source query, but you can also take the column alias of the display or return value of the query.

This example has page item with a popup lov that is a select from the sample EMP table with displayvalue: ename, return value: empno, additional column job. When I select a value, the page item P24_JOB gets set to the value of the job for the selected record.

Shared component definition:

[image: shared component definition]

Page item popup lov settings. Note that you don't need more than 2 columns, you could also just set the page item to the display value or return value using that column alias.

[image: page item configuration]